# In general, can we find Delaunay Triangulations isomorphic Complete Graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-geometry

I would like to know if my solution to the following problem is correct:

> Let $K_n$ be the complete graph on $n$ vertices. For arbitrary $n \ge 2$ either draw an example of a point set $P$ in the plane which's Delaunay Triangulation is isomorphic to $K_n$ or show that such an example does not exist in general.

Here is my reasoning: Such an example does not exist in general since $K_5$ is not planar, but a Delaunay Triangulation has to be planar.

Comment: Pretty much. See: [Delaunay Graph class](https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1147).